# Access JavaScript variables inside the jQuery document.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I want to access variables lat and var lng as shown in the code below please suggest me the correct ways to access these variables in the .load

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function getLocation() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
     } else { 
       x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
     }
   }    
   function showPosition(position) {
     var lat= position.coords.latitude; 
     var lng= position.coords.longitude;    
   }    
   $(".content").load("page1.php?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lng);
 });
```

I want to call var lat and var lng as shown in the code below please suggest me the currect ways to call this variables in the .load

Comment: Why not put your `$(".content").load` *inside* the `showPosition` function?

Comment: First, it doesn't look like you're passing a `position` object to your `showPosition()` function anywhere. Second, try moving your `$(".content").load()...` inside the `showPosition()` function.

Comment: @beercodebeer there's no need to pass the object - he already just passed a function reference so the caller will automatically invoke that function with the correct parameters.

Comment: Yeah, his question was edited shortly after I posted that comment, @Alnitak.

Comment: Rocket Hazmat it does not also work inside the showPosition funtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getCurrentPosition` function is asynchronous - the callback is invoked sometime later and execution continues with the rest of the function.

As such, the call to `.load` should be made within the `showPosition` function itself.

Don't forget that you must also call `getLocation()` to start the whole process off.

For convenience, here's an untested plugin wrapper that I've just knocked up that converts the `getCurrentLocation` call to a Promise interface:

```
(function($) {
    $.geolocate = function(options) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(def.resolve, def.reject, options);
        } else {
            def.reject("location not available");
        }
        return def.promise();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

usage:

```
$.geolocate().done(function(pos) {
    // use pos here
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude; 
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    ...
}).fail(function(err) {
    // 'err' is a PositionError object (if supported but not permitted)
    // or a string if geolocation isn't even supported.
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/SD79R/

Comment: Alnitak I check your code but it does not pass the variables to the .load. I use .load() in $.geolocate().done(function(pos){} in this funtion

Comment: @user3719363 I had an inconsistency on `pos` vs `position` - did you perhaps copy that into your code?

Answer (score -1):

You could move them up to `.ready()`'s scope:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lat;
    var lng;

    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }    
    function showPosition(position) {
        lat= position.coords.latitude; 
        lng= position.coords.longitude;    
    }    
    $(".content").load("page1.php?latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lng);
});
```

Comment: That will resolve the reference errors, but `showPosition()` won't be called to assign values for `lat` and `lng` until after `.load()`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Oh, very true. I misunderstood OP's problem. Moving the call to `load()` inside `showPosition()` is the answer.